# AddOrUpdate in Entity Framework 7

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to implement my own `AddOrUpdate` since Entity Framework doesn't contain this function for now. (And I need it)

I know there are similar questions here, but either there's no answer or it was another problem.

So, I'm stuck when trying to implement the update-part. This is my code:

- @this: my DbSet of entries in the Database
- parameter: the attribute to check in the DB whether to entry already exists
- entries: all entries to either add or update

---

```
public static void AddOrUpdate<T>(this DbSet<T> @this, Func<T, object> parameter, params T[] entries) where T: class, IEntity
{
    IEnumerable<object> keysExisting = @this.Select(parameter);

    foreach (T entry in entries)
    {
        bool entryExistsAlready = keysExisting.Contains(parameter.Invoke(entry));
        if (!entryExistsAlready)
        {
            @this.Add(entry);
            return;
        }
        entry.Id = @this.First(w => parameter.Invoke(w).Equals(parameter.Invoke(entry))).Id;
        @this.Attach(entry);
        @this.Update(entry);
    }
}
```

and for completing the information, this is how I call the method (There's already an ApplicationUser stored in the DB, with the Email "test@test.de"):

```
db.ApplicationUsers.AddOrUpdate(s => s.Email,
        new ApplicationUser{Email="test@test.de", Attribute="modified attribute"}
        );
```

I tried with attaching the entry and without attaching. I'm always getting following exception (either on `Attach()` or, when don't attaching, on `Update()`:

> InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'ApplicationUser' cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked. When adding new entities, for most key types a unique temporary key value will be created if no key is set (i.e. if the key property is assigned the default value for its type). If you are explicitly setting key values for new entities, ensure they do not collide with existing entities or temporary values generated for other new entities. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached to the context.

Any idea, how I can update my entries?

**update:**

I already tried with reflection, just setting all values from each property, but ApplicationUser e.g. has the property `Role` which is not writeable. So I'd lose data from my method-call.

Comment: You can get the entity from database and then assign changed properties  from entry  to that entity and try doing the same.

Comment: @divya yes, but this is kind of a `Seed()`-method where I have to give complete objects. I don't always know what properties change.

Comment: Then you have to assign all properties...   Please refer this:      http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/update-entity-using-dbcontext.aspx

Comment: @divya this is generic. I don't know the class and I don't know the properties- your link shows how to set one property and set the state of the complete object to modified. The `AddOrUpdate` takes any object, not one specific from a class. I'd have to write the `AddOrUpdate()` for each class or doing it with reflection like a deep clone.

Comment: I think you can iterate through each property  of the generic class using reflection and then assigning each property to the original object.

Comment: No, it's not possible, it'd result in data-loss. e.g. IdentityUser (default class for using Identity in ASP Net Core) has the property roles without a get/set-accessor (not overrideable). I'd loose all my roles in the database for each user I want tp update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the convention that if all the properties that make up an entity’s primary key have default values (0, null, etc.) then the entity is new otherwise it already exists:

```
public TEntity AddOrUpdate<TEntity>(DbContext context, TEntity entity)
    where TEntity : class
{
    context.Entry(entity).State =
        context.KeyValuesFor(entity).All(IsDefaultValue)
            ? EntityState.Added
            : EntityState.Modified;

    return entity;
}

private static bool IsDefaultValue(object keyValue)
{
    return keyValue == null
           || (keyValue.GetType().IsValueType
               && Equals(Activator.CreateInstance(keyValue.GetType()), keyValue));
}
```

Reference:

https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/05/03/the-key-to-addorupdate/

Comment: very nice! the link was really helpful too!